# Ubuntu overheats after starting from hibernation, but not after restarting

Tags: 13.10, hibernate, overheating

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit
Recently I have upgraded to 13.10 from 13.04 and noticed that Laptop is overheating (psensor temp ~80). But after I restart, temperature returns to normal (psensor ~56)

So I guess this has to do something with hibernation, because Laptop doesnt heat if I do proper shutdown every time. Any ideas how to fix this? I also checked startup applications, nothing unusual app found.

Also I have tlp installed, thought that it will help, but it didnt!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 uses kernel 3.13 and since 3.13 there is a major bug in controlling the fans!

I saw reports about affected HP and DELL laptops, and even Macbook Air. The symptom on my HP Compaq nx8220 is that the fan speed is set according to the temperature, but only once at boot time or when resumed after suspend! At boot time the temp is usually medium and the fan stays at medium speed. But after resume the temp is low, the fan stays off and the system overheats easily.

I was able to fix it today (July 13 2014) with a pre-release of kernel 3.13.0-32 from https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

**Careful users should wait a few days to get this fixed kernel as a normal update!**

From what I have read the problem was a kernel patch called "ACPI / AC: convert ACPI ac driver to platform bus" which has now been reverted in kernel 3.13.0-31 and higher.